# How to play a sound from audio tag in D3js selection?

Tags: audio, d3.js, playback

In D3js, what is the equivalent of:

JS: `htmlAudioTag.play()`
jQuery: `jqHtmlAudioTag.trigger('play')`;

I have tried

```
d3HtmlAudioTag.call('play');
```

but got something likve "objcct doesn't support apply function."

```
d3HtmlAudioTag.call(play);
```

says play is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

`d3` is not a `jQuery` replacement and it does not *proxy* arbitrary function calls down to the element.

The most natural way of doing it is to get the node and play it using JS: `d3HtmlAudioTag.node().play()`.

However, if you do want to use the `call` syntax, you can do the following:

```
function play(selection) { 
    selection.each(function (d, i) { this.play(); });
}
d3HtmlAudioTag.call(play);
```